# How can I handle "The page has expired due to inactivity."

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Currently, I am trying to make a user generator for a website and there is a fundemantal problem that I've been facing. The code below works but what it prints out is

> The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again

I have seen some of those solutions including using xsrf-token but either I am doing something wrong or it is not related to token.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
 s.get('http://www.watchill.org/register')
 token = s.cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"]
 agent = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36 OPR/62.0.3331.116",
         "XSRF-TOKEN":token}
 r = s.post('http://www.watchill.org/register',headers=agent)
 print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser"))
```

Comment: You need send value of `<meta name="csrf-token" content="XXX">`. Recommend to check what data is send if you click `ÜYE OL` and simulate it

Comment: The data consists of name, username, email,password and _token. but is it the lack of data that causes the expiration

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your CSRF token which is invalid.
I didn't check if this code is doing what's your aiming to but it does not return page expired message:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getXsrf(cookies):
    for cookie in s.cookies:
       if cookie.name =='XSRF-TOKEN':
          return cookie.value

with requests.Session() as s:
 s.get('http://www.watchill.org/register')
 xsrf = getXsrf(s.cookies)

 headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36 OPR/62.0.3331.116"}
 headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = xsrf
 r = s.post('http://www.watchill.org/register',headers=headers)
 print(BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser"))
```

Comment: Same as my code. All you have done is to take the cookie section out of the with section and making it function